# PHP error issue

Tags: php, offset

Good afternoon people.
I'm to ask some help about PHP error.I've this code that reports an error, but I don't understand what I can modify.

Error reported is:

Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/bat/rd-search.php on line 53 that is this string of code:

```
$final_result[$file_count]['page_title'][] = $page_title[1];
```

the code is:

```
  $contents = file_get_contents($file);
  preg_match("/\<title\>(.*)\<\/title\>/", $contents, $page_title); //getting page title
  if (preg_match("#\<body.*\>(.*)\<\/body\>#si", $contents, $body_content)) { //getting content only between <body></body> tags
    $clean_content = strip_tags($body_content[0]); //remove html tags
    $clean_content = preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $clean_content); //remove duplicate whitespaces, carriage returns, tabs, etc

    $found = strpos_recursive(mb_strtolower($clean_content, 'UTF-8'), $search_term);

    $final_result[$file_count]['page_title'][] = $page_title[1]; 
    $final_result[$file_count]['file_name'][] = preg_replace("/^.{3}/", "\\1", $file);
  }

  for ($j = 0; $j < count($template_tokens); $j++) {
    if (preg_match("/\<meta\s+name=[\'|\"]" . $template_tokens[$j] . "[\'|\"]\s+content=[\'|\"](.*)[\'|\"]\>/", $contents, $res)) {
      $final_result[$file_count][$template_tokens[$j]] = $res[1];
    }
  }
```

Thanks very much

Comment: which of the given lines is "line 53"?

Comment: What ever is on line 53, I assume the loop, index 0 doesn't not exist.

Comment: Sorry, I've forgot to insert the line 53 code. now I've posted it.